# Oracle Rank Column based on different Ordered column

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have data in table as follows :

ename    varchar2(10),
Amount   number(2)

| ename | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| B | 22 |
| B | 22 |
| A | 11 |
| A | 11 |
| C | 33 |
| C | 33 |
| C | 44 |
| C | 55 |
| C | 55 |
| C | 55 |

How can I achieve below two possible results :

1. First Expected result : Get **minimum Amount** of each ename ordered by Amount

| ename | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| A | 11 |
| B | 22 |
| C | 33 |

2. Second Expected result : New Column of Rank is ordered by Amount and same rank for each ename

| ename | Amount | RANK_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 11 | 1 |
| A | 11 | 1 |
| B | 22 | 2 |
| B | 22 | 2 |
| C | 33 | 3 |
| C | 33 | 3 |
| C | 44 | 3 |
| C | 55 | 3 |
| C | 55 | 3 |
| C | 55 | 3 |

I tried :

SELECT ename
,Amount
,dense_RANK() OVER (partition by ename ORDER BY Amount) AS RANK_ID
FROM
(
SELECT distinct ename
,Amount
FROM TEST_TABLE
)  ;

but could  got only :

| ename | Amount | RANK_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 11 | 1 |
| B | 22 | 1 |
| C | 33 | 1 |
| C | 44 | 2 |
| C | 55 | 3 |

for second problem i tried

SELECT ename
,Amount
,dense_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Amount) AS RANK_ID
FROM TEST_TABLE
;

but could got only :

| ename | Amount | RANK_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 11 | 1 |
| A | 11 | 1 |
| B | 22 | 2 |
| B | 22 | 2 |
| C | 33 | 3 |
| C | 33 | 3 |
| C | 44 | 4 |
| C | 55 | 5 |
| C | 55 | 5 |
| C | 55 | 5 |

Please help me get desired result set.

Comment: Your logic for the second case is not clear to me. Why do you get rank 3 for `C`? Because C comes after B? Or because 33 is greater than 22? If yes, why is `C | 44 -> Rank = 3`, instead of 4? What would be the result if you would have a record `C | 20`?

Comment: Each Group of A/B/C has "range of Amounts but these "ranges don't overlap" for group ..  
which means "C | 20 & C | 33"  is not possible as "B | 22" will fit in between.. 

I wanted output to be in increasing order of Amount, but Rank-id for each group to be same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is easy

```
Select ename, min(amount) as amount
From table
Group by ename
```

The second one would be

```
WITH t AS (
   SELECT 
      ename, Amount,
      min(amount) OVER (partition by ename) AS Min_amount
   FROM TEST_TABLE)
select ename, Amount,
   dense_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Min_amount) AS RANK_ID
from t
order by ename, Amount;
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XLMaItCi)

Comment: This gives me result like this.. 

A   --  11   -- 1
B   --  22   -- 1
C   --  33   -- 1
C   --  44   -- 2
C   --  55   -- 3

I didnt want to remove duplicate.. just want to add same rank for each ename.. ordered by Amout